# Change the value column of the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck what to add on my filter function. I have a dynamic rows that has multiple same class name.

```
<tr>
    <td class="row-col-1">CAPTAIN</td>
    <td class="row-col-2">AMERICA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="row-col-1">BABY</td>
    <td class="row-col-2">SHARP</td>
</tr>
```

I have managed to get the exact, but what I want is to change the value of other column with this same row.

```
('#table-body').find('.row-col-1').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'BABY';
});
```

Then I tried this to change the value of other column. The value of other column doesn't change.

```
('#table-body').find('.row-col-1').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'BABY';
}).find('.row-col-2').text('SHARK');
```

Comment: We need to see the HTML.

Comment: I just have a dynamic rows with same class name with different values.

Comment: @TylerRoper just added, thank you.

Comment: Thanks! If you select the `.row-col-1` that you're looking for, you can select one of its siblings using `.siblings()` instead of `.find()`. I.e., `.siblings('.row-col-2')`.

Comment: @TylerRoper I tried `.siblings('.row-col-2').text('SHARK')` at the end but the value still doesn't change.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h48gmc9b/ - It would seem something else is wrong then :/

Comment: @TylerRoper yes it is now working thanks to you. because there's another tag in my html inside of column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `next('td')`

```
$('#table-body').find('.row-col-1').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === 'BABY';
}).next('td').text('SHARK');
```